# MeanJS - Send Invite to users

Tags: mongodb, meanjs

Using meanjs, how would I go about sending an invite to a user via email.

I would assume that I would create a new user and set some sort of flag that they have been invited.

When the invited user accepts, they can either sign up via their email, facebook, etc, etc.

Has anyone done anything like this before? would love to see examples or gain some insight. thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a isRegistered/ isInvited flags to your model. This is pretty good in that it is pretty understandable from some one just viewing an document in the database.

Similarly you can add a status enum and then just have the user go from invited to registered, this way you can also manage password resets and user suspension from the same place.

One last method is creating a different collection of invites. I prefer this method because it is managing different entities in different spaces. In this case when a user is invited they get an email linking to a signup page and then you can just add in middleware to ensure that users are invited before they can signup.